# Insertion and retrieval of date values in sqlite blackberry

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

How to save a date(specified format dd-MM-yyyy) taken from a date field in BB JDE to a sqlite database.I want to insert and retrieve it from db in the above mentioned format.Retrieval would be based on range searching.

Comment: It will be nice if you explain your question. It is possible to get a date as the format specified in question, and then it can be stored in `sqlite` as `TEXT`, `REAL`, `INTEGER`. `Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.` - from section 1.2, Date and Time Datatype, http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.

Comment: This has been solved.Thanks for the reply though.